# Is it possible to suppress the display of all parameterized arguments when a test fails in pytest

Tags: pytest

I'm currently using python 3.5.1 and 3.6 and the latest versions of pytest.
When running pytest with parameterized tests i would like any failing tests to only display the test that failed and not all of the set up for the parameterized test.

To explain...

I have a number of tests that I have written using the @pytest.mark.parametrize decorator to allow me to run a test with many different inputs.

I also pass a list of ids for my parameterized arguments as shown in the example below:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('input_name12, output_name12',
    [
        ('chloroform', None),
        ('chloroform-d', (['deuterated'], '-d'))]
    ],
    ids=[
        "unlabelled chloroform",
        "chloroform deuterio-labelled with -d"
    ]
def test_isotope_extract(input_name12, output_name12):
    assert isotope_extract(input_name12) == output_name12
```

In some cases I have 10+ sets of arguments that I want to run in my tests.  This generally works ok. However, when I run the tests, if one or more of my parameterised tests fails the whole block of all of the parameterized test is output to the terminal for each failure. ie a failure for one of the tests in the above code would result in all of the code in that block being displayed in the terminal as well as the specific detail of which assertion failed.

Is there any way to suppress the display of the whole parameterized test, so that when I get a failure I only see the assertion that failed and the associated Id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because pytest prints the code of the function that failed. You can prevent that by using `--tb=short`.

Comment: Awesome. Just tried it out and it does exactly what I want.  Thanks for your help.